# Why does a database randomly throw dns error

Tags: postgresql, dns, digital-ocean, loopbackjs

I have a REST API (built in node.js, express, loopback framework) and very randomly I get the following error:
[image: API ERROR]

It happens so infrequently and everyone I ask says its a dns error, but I'm not sure how to fix it because it only happens for a second and then doesn't happen again for a while. My friend says that the server is making too many requests to the database and so the database ends up blocking it, but if this is true, I'm only testing the api with one mobile device right now, so I fear what will happen when more devices are using the system. Plus, I have a primary node and read-only node, so the database should be able to handle a decent amount of requests. How can I debug or fix this error permanently?

Comment: Would be useful to know what type of plan you have with Digital Ocean? Could be there is a request limit on it. Postgresql is not in charge of DNS, so I doubt it is at issue.

Comment: Well I'm running: Cluster configuration Primary + Standby - $100/mo.
Running on 2 CPU + 4 GB + 38 GB Disk Droplets. And I'm just testing the API. The API itself is running a shared CPU with 2GB Memory, and 50GB solid state. I'm actually running another API connected to the same database, and its throwing the same error. If I do run the API locally, it also throws the error at times

Comment: If I got the name right (which is difficult with a screenshot instead of text hence why it is not recommended and why I downvoted), note that there is a least one DNS error, see https://dnsviz.net/d/test-db-postgresql-nyc3-34288-do-user-7115232-0.a.db.ondigitalocean.com/dnssec/  Shouldn't be a big problem, but eventually no DNS error is without consequences. You sdhould also ask your provider, and as such at this stage your question is not really on topic about programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm so sorry. I realize the text would have been better. I didn't know what the problem was to be honest. 
```
Unhandled error in GET /restaurant/order-items?[where][paid]=true&[sortBy]=orderedOn: 500 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test-db-postgresql-nyc3-34288-do-user-7115232-0.a.db.ondigitalocean.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
```
I see the DNS error and have previously contacted digital ocean about it but they did not know how to solve it :/